# Vector bundle on a quadric

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The problem:

Consider the smooth quadric $Q=V(X_{0}X_{1}+X_{2}X_{3}+X_{4}^{2})\subset\mathbb{P}^{4}$ and
the line $L=V(X_{0},X_{2},X_{3})$ contained in it. Prove that there exists a vector bundle $F$ on $Q$ with a section vanishing exactly at $L$.

Comment: Is there a type in $L = V(X_0,X_2,X_3)?$ I don't see why $L \subseteq Q$. For instance $[0:0:0:0:1]$ is in $L$ but not in $Q$.