# Vector bundle on a quadric $Q$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The problem:

Consider the smooth quadric $Q=V(X_{0}X_{1}+X_{2}X_{3}+X_{4}^{2})\subset\mathbb{P}^{4}$ and the line $L=V(X_{0},X_{2},X_{4})$ contained in it. Prove that there exists a vector bundle $F$ on $Q$ with a section vanishing exactly at $L$.

The hardest thing is to get the transition matrices. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's happened? you've created a new account? you could just edit your question! http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601779/vector-bundle-on-a-quadric that's what we were waiting for it.

Answer (score 5):

Consider on $\mathbb P^4$ the three line bundles $\mathcal L_i=\mathcal O(H_i)\; (i=0,2,4) $ associated to the divisors $H_i=\{X_i=0\}$.
They have global sections $s_i\in \Gamma(\mathbb P^4,\mathcal L_i)$ vanishing exactly on $H_i$.
The vector bundle  $\mathcal L_0\oplus \mathcal L_2\oplus \mathcal L_4$ has a section vanishing exactly along $L=H_0\cap H_2\cap H_4$, namely  the section $s_0\oplus s_2\oplus s_4\in \Gamma(\mathbb P^4,\mathcal L_0\oplus\mathcal L_2\oplus\mathcal L_4)$
The line bundle $F=(\mathcal L_0\oplus\mathcal L_2\oplus \mathcal L_4)|Q$ then also has a section vanishing exactly along $L$, namely the restriction to $F$ of the section $s_0\oplus s_2\oplus s_4$.

[Note that there is no need for transition matrices.]

**Edit: the transition matrices**
The transition matrices required by JSong in his comment are easy to calculate .
Since the cocycle for $\mathcal O_{P^4}(1)$ is given by $g_{ij}=\frac{X_j}{X_i}$ on $\mathbb P^4$ the transition matrices for $F$ on $Q$ are the diagonal $3\times 3$ matrices $$G_{ij}=\operatorname{diag} (\frac{z_j}{z_i},\frac{z_j}{z_i},\frac{z_j}{z_i})\quad(0\leq i,j\leq 4)$$  ($z_i$ is the restriction of $X_i$ to $Q$)
The required section $s=s_0\oplus s_2\oplus s_4\in \Gamma(Q,F)$ which vanishes exactly along $L$ has in the chart $U_i=\{z_i\neq 0\}$ the expression $$s^{(i)}(z)=\frac{ z_0}{z_i}\oplus \frac{z_2}{z_i}\oplus \frac{z_4}{z_i}\in \mathbb C^3  \quad (z\in U_i)$$

Comment: Thanks. But I need to calculate the transition matrices. I've considered the open sets $U_{i}=\left\{x_{i}\neq 0\right\}$. Now, the idea is calculate the affine ideals of $Q\cap U_{i}$. Then, it is possible to relate the first sets of generators ($a_{0},b_{0}$) by the expression $(a_{0},b_{0})=A_{01}(a_{1},b_{1})$ and the matrix $A_{01}$ in the expression has entries regular in $U_{0}\cap U_{1}$ and is invertible in that open set. Continuing in this way all transition matrices are obtained. But what happens is that the calculations are difficult. Could anyone help?

Comment: Dear @JSong, I have provided the transition matrices in an edit.